Docker: Can't connect to container in bridge mode, only host mode
I've a simple docker container running gunicorn. When I run it on my desktop linux machine everything works exactly as expected. However when I move it over to my NAS, the container runs but I'm unable to connect to the running container. I suspect it's a networking issue but I'm not sure how to diagnose the issue.
Dockerfile
FROM python:latest

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY app app
COPY migrations migrations
COPY app.py config.py boot.sh ./
RUN chmod a+x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]

Compose file
services:
  backend:
    image: <private>/sensors
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - sensorsVolume:/db

volumes:
  sensorsVolume:
    external: true
    name: sensorsVolume

When I run the container I can see gunicorn attaching and listening on port 5000
[+] Running 1/1
 ✔ Container root-backend-1  Created                                                                                                                          0.3s
Attaching to backend-1
backend-1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
backend-1  | INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
backend-1  | [2024-10-15 07:40:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 23.0.0
backend-1  | [2024-10-15 07:40:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
backend-1  | [2024-10-15 07:40:49 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
backend-1  | [2024-10-15 07:40:49 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8

However all curl requests to either localhost on the NAS or to the NAS IP (192.168.86.250) fail with a timeout.
I can connect to the running container and curl to either localhost or the assigned IP and receive and answer
root@eb336e86cfa7:/etc# curl http://172.19.0.2:5000/
<p>Hello, World!</p>

I'm at a loss to understand where to examine next.
Some extra points

I've used cross-compilation features of docker build to build an arm64/v8 image on an amd64 host
docker build -t /sensors:latest --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64/v8  .

I've tried altering the compose file to attach to the external IP of the NAS in the ports section but that also didn't help.


Here's a list of interfaces in case it helps.
# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: end0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:62:66:d0:08:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.86.250/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.86.255 scope global dynamic end0
       valid_lft 11254sec preferred_lft 11254sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:400c:a461:116a:a7ad/64 scope global temporary dynamic
       valid_lft 600984sec preferred_lft 82525sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:6838:6a34:4937:9c47/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 514646sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:fa10:5221:1615:fa01/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 428306sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:2191:8fe5:707d:99b7/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 341966sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:ba7c:59ef:3f27:78db/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 255626sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:3107:f77c:11b0:9932/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 169286sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:ccec:f060:4721:79b8/64 scope global temporary deprecated dynamic
       valid_lft 82947sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 2406:5a00:343a:fc00:6662:66ff:fed0:8d6/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 383sec preferred_lft 383sec
    inet6 fdb3:62f5:4651:1:6662:66ff:fed0:8d6/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 2591815sec preferred_lft 604615sec
    inet6 fe80::6662:66ff:fed0:8d6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enx646266d008d7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 64:62:66:d0:08:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:fc:cf:20:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:fcff:fecf:2095/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
36: br-4a76e3a9c6a4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:6c:d8:d1:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::42:6cff:fed8:d1b2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
47: br-fb23a92d9ede: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:80:3b:d8:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::42:80ff:fe3b:d8d3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


This may be due to https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-access-container-webui-in-bridge-mode-only-host-mode/142577/15 but currently there doesn't seem to be a solution.
